What is the name of the thing which exists between src/ and build/ and pkg/ directories in an embedded project?
What is the name of the thing which contains the following?
(CamelCased names for things where I am choosing a descriptive name but I don't necessarily know what the accepted term is.)
--- a Compiler
    --- responsible for turning SourceFiles into SourceBinaries
    --- example:
        --- gcc
--- a Linker
    --- responsible for combining binaries from compiler into
        complete ApplicationBinaries
    --- example:
        --- ld (The GNU Linker)
--- SourceFiles
    --- responsible for containing human-readable application
        logic
    --- example:
        --- src/
        --- source/
        --- src/main.cpp
        --- src/__init__.py
--- a BuildDirectory
    --- responsible for containing the output of the
        BuildSystem + Linker + Compiler
    --- example:
        --- build/
        --- bin/
        --- out/
--- a BuildSystem
    --- responsible for driving the compiler and linker to build
        for the chosen ApplicationPlatform
    --- example:
        --- make
        --- Ninja
        --- VisualStudio
--- a PlatformConfiguration
    --- responsible for applying configuration data allowing the
        BuildSystem + Linker + Compiler to produce output
        compatible with the ApplicationPlatform
    --- example:
        --- ./configure.sh
        --- kconfig
        --- cmake
--- Tests
    --- responsible for proving the built ApplicationBinary does
        what it was intended to do
    --- example:
        --- CPPUTest
        --- CTest
--- Packager
    --- responsible for combining ApplicationBinary with other
        ProjectOutputs into a SourceDistribution or
        BinaryDistribution
    --- example:
        --- CPack

I've worked around embedded engineers and been someone who supports embedded engineers for a long time. I don't know what this word is and I know terminology can be difficult to nail down for sure in this field, but it seems like there should be a name for this as a whole.
Hopefully I'm missing an obvious option that everyone already knows... :D

I don't think there's a common name for this collection of things, but on some systems it might be called a Project or Solution.

All of these components simply means “build system”. The most common term used to refer to the entire system that orchestrates the compilation, linking, testing, and packaging of software.

In embedded C or just C projects in general, isn't the build system most commonly a reference to the tool that processes the logic for executing the compiler and linker in order to produce the final binary?
I'm specifically trying to disambiguate the terminology used in this realm as it will help me teach others down the line.

The term that embraces all what you show is called "project" in the world I live in. It also includes documents like requirements specification, architecture, design, test strategy, and so on. Development is by far not only "source -> (tools) -> result."
Do not mix this with "project" used by different IDEs or in other contexts. For the pedants among us, it is quite unsatisfying that the same term is used for different things in different contexts. That might be a reason why some IDEs invented terms like "solution" or "workspace" with different scopes. Use these only in connection with a certain IDE.
The tool set to build and test the artifacts of a project is commonly called "development environment." It does not need to but mostly does include the IDE, in cases there are more than one. But as we use it, this does not include the sources or the directory hierarchy.
The directory hierarchy is mainly independent of the development environment, though some build systems strongly suggest a certain hierarchy and naming. However, some customers have their very own idea how the hierarchy should look like.

Edit

I'm mostly looking for a black-box term which applies to the full scope of what the developer interacts with in between source repository pull/push steps in their workflow.

As I said, you can be more specific with "(project) development environment" as it limits the scope the steps developers take. That is, if you exclude the other members of the project team.
(I repeat.) Please note that there is more in development than the source and its transformation to a software product. Each developer needs requirements, architecture and design specifications and other documents before even touching source code.
I'm really sure that there is no single and widespread accepted and used word, but my view is necessarily limited. This might be because it is no need for it, because in real life projects are heavily different. In my experience an engineer has to learn and negotiate the details in each and every project, including the terms to use.

I'm definitely one of those pedants.

So I'm afraid you have to stand this blurriness, as so many of us, in so many domain of our lives. Beware, we are at the borders to opinions here. And these are off-topic at StackOverflow.

Would the "project" you describe be more completely subclassed as an "embedded project"?

No, please do not load this term with another meaning. Most developers imagine an "embedded project" as a project that targets an embedded control product.

This is very useful, thank you. I'm mostly looking for a black-box term which applies to the full scope of what the developer interacts with in between source repository pull/push steps in their workflow.
I'm definitely one of those pedants. The broadness of the word "project" is one of the issues I have with it, since it's applicable in so many contexts. Would the "project" you describe be more completely subclassed as an "embedded project"?
